# Translation operator in polar coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, coordinate-systems

Accordingly to Stone's theorem the generator of a strongly continuous one-parameter unitary group is self-adjoint.

The translation operator in the radial direction  in Cartesian coordinates is unitary since

$$\int{\psi^*(x-a,y-b)\psi(x-a,y-b)}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int{\psi^*(x,y)\psi(x,y)}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

But in polar coordinates we have

$$\int{r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta\psi^*(r-c,\theta)\psi(r-c,\theta)}\neq \int{r \,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta\psi^*(r,\theta)\psi(r,\theta)}.$$

Does that mean that the generator of the translation  operator in radial direction in Cartesian coordinates is self-adjoint and in polar coordinates it is not?

Comment: The Cartesian coordinate version of the ``radial translation operation"  would be $\psi(x,y)\mapsto \psi(x-ax/\sqrt{x^2+y^2},y-ay/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ rather than what you have.   It is not a self adjoint operation..

Comment: you are right . I was confusing the to operation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is exactly the problem. The generator is a self-adjoint operator in the Cartesian case, and a non-self-adjoint operator in the Polar case. In strict mathematical terms, $ \frac{d}{dr}$ is a maximal symmetric operator with no self-adjoint extension. This is all very neatly explained in the article of Paz https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0009016v2